# Returning two function from function

Tags: php

I am calling a search function from my object and in return i want to send the result plus some message so can i return two variable one with array and one with the message  like $data and $message

```
$this->query=("select * from user where pno='".$search."'");
$rd = $this->executeQuery();
return @$data = $rd->fetch_assoc();

return $message;
```

when it get back to

```
$result=$user->search($result);
```

how can i fetch the result from it 
Thanks

Comment: What is `$message` and where does it come from?  What could it contain?  Can you show us more context with your code?  The best way to tackle this problem will be *very* different depending on your answer.

Comment: $message is somewhat like this 
}else {
$error = "";
$i = 1;
foreach ($validate->getError() as $err){
$error.= "$i) ". $err." "."<br/>";
$i++;
}
foreach ($errors_all as $errs){
$error.= "$i) ". $errs." "."<br/>";
$i++;
}
return $error;

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @moe's answer is perfectly correct, you probably don't want to do that for error handling.

Why?

Because next you'll find yourself *having to return a two-element array from ****every**** function* with the real data in one element and a possible error in the other, and then you're going to need to check the error every single time, even if you can't do anything about it.

That's gonna get tedious *really* quick.

**You're dealing with errors, so treat them like errors!**  When an error happens, [throw an exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).  If the calling code *can* elegantly recover from an error, it can look for and expect to deal with the exception.  If the calling code *can't* recover from an error, then the exception will crawl up the chain until it hits [a default exception handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php), which you can configure to elegantly and delicately handle the responsibility of telling the user that something broke.

Comment: Ya when I was writing mine, I failed to read the part you are trying to handle error. My solution was to returning multiple variables. Error handling is a separate thing :-)

Answer (score 2):

put your variables in an array and return the array.

so your function can return this for example:

`return array($data, $message);`

then you can call your function like this:

`list($data, $message) = search('hello');`

Comment: or `list($data, $message) = search('hello');` as an alternative.

Comment: I edited my solution almost immediately and changed it to what you have. It should be that already